# Is it possible to do a mousedown function inside an element, but not the elements childen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

For example I have this code:

```
<style>
    .wrapper { width:1200px; height:800px; }
    .column { width:900px; height:800px; margin:auto -0; }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="column"> </div>
</div>
```

I want a mousedown function to be called when you click outside of the "column" but not inside the column. Is this possible?

My current non-working code is:

```
$(".wrapper:not(.column)").mousedown(function(){
     alert("test");
});
```

UPDATE: I am actually using classes, not IDs.

Comment: you don't need the :not(#column) - #wrapper will suffice since it's selecting by id.

Comment: In my actual code, I'm using classes. Will this effect anything?

Comment: still, your selector won't select the .column div since it doesn't have the "wrapper" class, so you still don't need the :not(.column).

Comment: Using the classes will mean you need a more general approach, have a look at my answer to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work by stopping `mousedown` events on elements with class `column` from bubbling, and will work so long as column elements are strictly contained within wrapper elements.

```
$(".wrapper").mousedown(function(evt) {
    alert("Mouse down!");
});

$(".column").mousedown(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This worked! Is there any reason the other examples are more proper in any way?

Comment: No. It's the same idea as Brandon Montgomery's answer but fully implemented.

Answer (score 3):

What you'll want to do is put a mousedown event handler on your #column div also, but in that event handler, you want to prevent the event from bubbling up to its container elements.

```
$("#column").mousedown(function (e) {
  var event = e || window.event;
  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
  } 
});
```

Here's a full example: http://jsfiddle.net/YrXSM/

Comment: I think in jQuery e.stopPropagation() should work across all browsers.

Comment: You are using jQuery and therefore don't need to do that IE compatibility stuff. The event object is passed in into the handler, and e.stopPropagation() works inside the handler.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can stop the function from being called from the children, but you can detect what was clicked.  I'm not sure if this is the *best* way to do it, but this should work:

```
$("#wrapper").mousedown(function(e){
  if($(e.target).attr('id') == 'wrapper')
  {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wrapper").mousedown(function(e) {
    if (this !== e.target) { return; }
    alert("test"); 
});
```

So, basically, we are testing whether the `.wrapper` element was clicked directly. If not, we disregard the event by returning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#wrapper").mousedown(function(){
     alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to assign another event to #container onMouseDown that does nothing, and then prevents the event from bubbling up.

Answer (score 0):

The example given using e.target is the best option, however there is the possibility in the general case that your .mousedown() function is bound to a more complicated selector, if that is the case you can use the following code.

```
$(".wrapper").mousedown(function(e){
    if ($('.wrapper').filter(e.target).size() > 0) {
         alert("test");
    }
});
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/9RPcb/1/